# How to expose external service for Jenkins installed using Helm in a k8s cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I installed Jenkins via Helm in a k8s cluster in AWS:

`helm install --name my-jenkins stable/jenkins`

However I don't see the external endpoint service. How do I access Jenkins URL?

[image: Kubernetes Dashboard]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out after a bit of research. Here are the steps to be followed.

1) `helm search jenkins`

2) Change stable/jenkins default values:

```
 helm inspect values stable/jenkins > /tmp/jenkins.values
 sudo vi /tmp/jenkins.values
```

3) Update the following values in the jenkins.values file:

> serviceType: LoadBalancer

4) Install helm stable/jenkins

`helm install stable/jenkins --values /tmp/jenkins.values --name myjenkins --namespace jenkins`

5) Get status:

```
kubectl get svc --namespace jenkins
```

You can view the external-IP

Comment: You can create your own values file just containing that one line; Helm will merge it with the chart's default values.  You do not need to have root permissions (`sudo`) to do any of this.